# R: Apply to slices of an array and return an array

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I want to find the simplest way to apply a function across slices of an array, where each application of the function returns a matrix, and receive a sensible array object as the final answer.

I feel like there should be a simple way to do this with apply function, but I feel like I need a `simplify = 'array'` option, which would be super convenient. The closest I get is this:

```
dims = c(2,3,10,4,5)
arr = array(runif(prod(dims)),dim = dims, dimnames = 
          list(
            paste0('a',1:dims[1]),
            paste0('b',1:dims[2]),
            paste0('c',1:dims[3]),
            paste0('d',1:dims[4]),
            paste0('e',1:dims[5])
          ))

result = apply(arr, c(4,5), function(x) apply(x, c(3), function(y) (y - y[,1])^2 ) )
```

The `result` should be an array with dimension `c(2,3,10,4,5)` or some permutation thereof.

I could get to the right form by calling `as.array` on `result` with the appropriate dimensions, but there should be an easier way that preserves the `dimnames` automatically.

Comment: To do it with `apply`, specify the margins you want to keep: `apply(arr, 2:5, function(x){mean(x^2)})`

Comment: @alistaire - that should definitely be an answer - it is super simple. `apply(arr^2, 2:5, mean)` would even work in this particular case.

Comment: Sorry I gave a bad example. I will correct the example to comport with the wording and the actual goal of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `aaply` function in `plyr` package. This is one of several apply functions in this package, where the naming convention is that `aa` in `aaply` stands for array to array.

```
dims = c(2,3,10,4,5)
arr = array(runif(prod(dims)),dim = dims, dimnames = 
          list(
            paste0('a',1:dims[1]),
            paste0('b',1:dims[2]),
            paste0('c',1:dims[3]),
            paste0('d',1:dims[4]),
            paste0('e',1:dims[5])
          ))

aresult = (aaply(arr, c(4,5), function(x) aaply(x, c(3), function(y) (y - y[,1])^2 ) ) )
result = aperm(abind(aresult), c(4,5,3,1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a multidimensional array with `apply`, specify the margins you want to keep. It's easier to visualize in two dimensions:

```r
m <- matrix(1, 2, 3)

m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1

apply(m, 1, sum)
#> [1] 3 3
```

—iterating over rows keeps that dimension, and collapses the unmentioned column one. For the more complicated array in question, then,

```r
res <- apply(arr, 2:5, function(x){mean(x^2)})
# or even just apply(arr^2, 2:5, mean) (h/t @thelatemail)

str(res)
#>  num [1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5] 0.313 0.215 0.32 0.29 0.288 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr [1:2] "b1" "b2"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:4] "d1" "d2" "d3" "d4"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:5] "e1" "e2" "e3" "e4" ...
```